# ef core 2.2 preview migration change

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-2.1

we just updated Entity Framework Core from  2.1 to 2.2.Preview3.
It seems that the migrator / modelbuilder changed and I am wondering if it is a bug or fix.

If have the following Entity:

```
public class User {
    public string UserName { get; set; }
    public Guid? PasswordGUID { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("PasswordGUID")]
    public Password Password { get; set; }
}
```

The entity class Password has no navigation property to the entity class User.

With EfCore 2.1 the User Password relationship got the following lines in the modelsnapshot:

```
...
u.Property<Guid?>("PasswordGUID");
...
u.HasIndex("PasswordGUID");
...
u.HasOne("Password", "Password")
    .WithMany()
    .HasForeignKey("PasswordGUID");
```

Now after the update from EfCore 2.1 to 2.2.Preview3 (entity classes did not change) the model got the following changes:

```
...
u.Property<Guid?>("PasswordGUID")
    .IsRequired();
...
u.HasIndex("PasswordGUID")
    .IsUnique();
...
u.HasOne("Password", "Password")
    .WithOne()
    .HasForeignKey("PasswordGUID")
    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade);
```

So as stated above, my question is: Is this correct? Do I now have to "revert" these changes in the modelBuilder Fluent API or is this a bug?

Sidenote: Strangely I noted with EfCore 2.1 the same behaviour, when I deleted the Attribute "[ForeignKey("PasswordGUID")]"